# Global Temporary table send by ref cursor

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am building an application with PHP and Oracle.

I created a procedure in oracle and used to send data from oracle global temporary table

```
open p_stockledger_cur FOR SELECT * from temp_stockledger;
```

this is the last line in my procedure to return the data.

In php my all procedures are working, but only those are not working which returning data from global temporary table.

```
$CursorResource = oci_execute('my_ref_cursor');
oci_fetch_array('my_ref_cursor')
```

but here php always gives me error,

```
oci_fetch_array(): ORA-08103: object no longer exists
```

Any help..

Comment: In short try recreating the global temporary table with `on commit preserve rows` clause.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem